brms simple hierarchical model
Help me to understand, how to build a simple hierarchical model. Suppose we have a categorical variable, and we want to model Intercept and Slope for each level. Since level "b" has almost no data available, we would want the model to pull information for this level from the global means.
library(brms)
dd = data.frame(y = numeric(), x = numeric(), c = character())
dd = rbind(dd,
  {thisX = rnorm(1000); data.frame(y = -4 + 1 * thisX, x = thisX, c = "a")},
  {thisX = rnorm(10);   data.frame(y =  2 + 1 * thisX, x = thisX, c = "b")},
  {thisX = rnorm(1000); data.frame(y =  4 + 3 * thisX, x = thisX, c = "c")}
)
model <- brm(
    y~ 1 + x + (1 + x | c),
    data = dd,
    family = gaussian(),
    prior= c(
        prior(normal(0, 0.1), class = "b"),
        prior(gamma(1, 10), class = "sd")
        )
)
fixef(model)
ranef(model)

Expectation:
Global        Intercept ~0    Slope ~2
Global+a:     Intercept =-4   Slope =1
Global+b:     Intercept ~0.1  Slope ~1.9  (because not enough data is available)
Global+c:     Intercept =4    Slope =3

What am I missing? I tried setting strong priors on the random sd, and tried replacing random component with the cross-effect, both to no avail. Thank you in advance for any hints.

I think your data simulation process is backward. You use rnorm() to generate x values but then you just transform x to generate y, without adding any error. So the model will be a perfect fit. You need to add the rnorm() noise to y, not to x.

I could add +rnorm(0.2) to each y to simulate noise. My problem here is that the model has some kind of redundancy, where Intercept and random intercepts are correlated - each chain stops at some unique global and random intercepts, all perfectly describing the data. Not sure how to force it to make the global intercept a global mean, not just some value.

Yes, that was my point. The model is perfectly describing the data because you have not included any residual variation in y that is not explained by x. The rnorm() for x is not including any noise. The linear mixed model is Y = Xb + Zu + epsilon. The way you have simulated the data has no error (epsilon).

So there is nothing wrong with the model, just the data simulation process. Try {thisX = runif(1000, 0, 1), data.frame(y = -4 + 1 * thisX + rnorm(0, 1), x = thisX, c = "a")} and so forth, for each of your three lines where you simulate the data.
